# Log in into Outlook meeting room account

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

Is it possible to log in into an Office365 Meeting Room user?

I need to use an android app for each Meeting Room of my company and get the meeting room bookings to save them into a shared local repository.

I have to use [Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) to get the meetings, is it possible?

*"The meeting rooms have resource accounts, not user accounts. This means they cannot be logged into"*.. is this true??

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, you cannot log in to resource accounts. Today in order to access meeting room mailboxes, you need to implement the [client credential flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) and [gain access to all mailboxes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/) in the organization.

A couple of samples:

- [Python](https://github.com/jasonjoh/python_clientcred)
- [Java](https://github.com/jasonjoh/java-calendar-demo)

Comment: So this wouldn't work? https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/insite/news/intnews2/email_work_jun-2013/resource_accounts/ 
"There's another way of opening resource accounts - sharing the password with other people and signing directly into it."
- Thanks

Comment: Nope, the API does not support delegate access.

Comment: So I can't login into a resource account using Outlook API in any way, right? Thanks

Comment: The Outlook APIs don't "log in" to anything. You can use the API to access meeting room mailboxes, you just need a token which grants you that access. Today the only way is client credentials.